# command-line-runner selenium EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, selenium, selenium-side-runner

I using docker-compose

in ubuntu container with Dockerfile I install

RUN npm install -g selenium-side-runner

Then i run try run from www-data user

```
selenium-side-runner --output-directory /tmp /application/src/www.opendi.co.uk.side --server http://chrome-hub.local:4444/wd/hub
```

get

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'side-suite-www.opendi.co.uk'
at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:987:3)
at runProject (/usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/dist/index.js:240:15)
at runAll (/usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/dist/index.js:345:10)
at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/dist/index.js:390:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
errno: -13,
syscall: 'mkdir',
code: 'EACCES',
path: 'side-suite-www.opendi.co.uk'
```

Where selenium-side-runner try create this directory ? in /tmp ? in this location it can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/application/src/www.opendi.co.uk.side
```

this is the path that doesn't exist inside docker. It is trying to create the [www.opendi.co.uk.side](http://www.opendi.co.uk.side) directory

Remove that and try:

```
selenium-side-runner --output-directory /tmp --server http://chrome-hub.local:4444/wd/hub
```